# Getting error AADST50013 for OBO flow using Azure AD B2C on .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am following this official MS [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#protocol-diagram) to implement the OBO flow for two secure Web APIs (let's say Web API 1 and 2) using Azure AD B2C. That previous link points out to the following [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof) on Git.

Basically, I am using the same code:

MyController.cs

```
string[] scopes = { "profile.read.basic", "user.read" };
UserProfile profile = null;
        
try
{
   string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenantId);
            
   ClaimsPrincipal principal = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
   //Grab the Bearer token from the HTTP Header using the identity bootstrap context. This requires SaveSigninToken to be true at Startup.Auth.cs
   var bootstrapContext = principal.Identities.First().BootstrapContext?.ToString();

   // Creating a UserAssertion based on the Bearer token sent by TodoListClient request.
   //urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer is the grant_type required when using On Behalf Of flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow
   UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
            
   // Creating a ConfidentialClientApplication using the Build pattern (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications)
   var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithClientSecret(appKey)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .Build();

   // Acquiring an AuthenticationResult for the scope user.read, impersonating the user represented by userAssertion, using the OBO flow
   AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
```

On StartUp.cs I had to set up the SaveSigninToken to true

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { SaveSigninToken = true };
            }, options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
```

When I run the Web API using Swagger and hit the tested endpoint the following line of code:

```
AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
```

thrown the following error:

*AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.]
Trace ID: c0d53284-12f3-4ab0-a42c-d7c35e2ad300
Correlation ID: e37849e8-938b-441e-bd80-d1612733dc17
Timestamp: 2021-08-20 22:13:53Z*

From Azure AD B2C I have granted permission to Web API 1 from the App Registration to communicate to the Web API 2.

For the given error, I have been doing some research/ investigation as well as trying a few different approaches but no luck.

Does any one know how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If these really are tokens issued via Azure AD B2C endpoint, then it simply is not compatible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-developer-notes#oauth-20-application-authorization-flows

Your error code, however, shows you are trying to use the Azure AD endpoint, probably of your Azure AD B2C tenant.

In which case, you seem to be using an Azure AD B2C signed token, and trying to do OBO against the Azure AD endpoint, and both use different signing keys. This therefore will not work.

Only the Azure AD endpoint will do OBO flow. I.e. Users tokens issued from Azure AD token endpoint, and performing OBO against the same endpoint with the users AAD token.

**AAD endpoint**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

**AAD B2C endpoint**: `https://contoso.b2clogin.com/<tenant>/<B2C-policy-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

You can't use these two endpoints together for different things.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. Now, I have a better understanding on it. However, still trying to figure out how to achieve it. Do you know or point out to a documentation on how to make the communication between two secured web apis? I was testing with Client Credential flow but getting an 401 unauthorized error

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow